# Checkbox check all by name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ScnQT/207/) which will select checkbox in the page.

But i wanted to check the group of checkbox with common class name.

Here is the [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ScnQT/208/) I have for that.

How can i achieve this ?

Here's the Script i have so far

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.check:button').toggle(function(){
        $('input:checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
        $(this).val('uncheck all')
    },function(){
        $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
        $(this).val('check all');        
    })
})
```

Comment: Your JSFiddle demo has a typo. `id="CheckAll1"` -> `#CheckAll`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just replace input by your class name.

```js
$("#checkAll1").change(function () {
    $(".1:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
});

$("#checkAll2").change(function () {
    $(".2:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
    <p><label><input type="checkbox" id="checkAll1"/> Check all</label></p>
    
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Loads of checkboxes</legend>
<p><label><input type="checkbox" class="1" /> Option 1</label></p>
<p><label><input type="checkbox" class="1" /> Option 2</label></p>
<p><label><input type="checkbox" class="1" /> Option 3</label></p>      
    </fieldset>
</form>

<form action="#">
    <p><label><input type="checkbox" id="checkAll2"/> Check all</label></p>
    
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Loads of checkboxes</legend>
<p><label><input type="checkbox" class="2" /> Option 1</label></p>
<p><label><input type="checkbox" class="2" /> Option 2</label></p>
<p><label><input type="checkbox" class="2" /> Option 3</label></p>      
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

LINK : http://jsfiddle.net/4zpu4m0w/1/

Regards.

Comment: Is that really a valid classname?

Comment: don't think so, but i just used his example and make it work :)

Answer (score 1):

You should give same class(say `checkall`) to checkboxes that check/uncheck all elements in group and have a change handler that only target the checkboxes from sibling fieldset of closest p element:

```
$(".checkall").change(function () {
  $(this).closest('p').next().find(':checkbox').prop('checked',  $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/snwqh6eh/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#checkAll1").change(function () {
    $(".1").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
});

$("#checkAll2").change(function () {
    $(".2").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [jQuery.data()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)

```
$(".js-check-group").change(function () {
    var elem = $(this);
    $('.' + elem.data('group')).prop('checked', elem.prop("checked"));
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ScnQT/211/

Comment: Note also the var for $(this) .. saves time by only getting "this" once with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I would to it like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll2" class="checkAll"/>

$(".checkAll").change(function () {
    var myInputs = $(this).closest("form").find("fieldset input:checkbox");
    myInputs.each(function(){
        $(this).prop('checked', !$(this).prop("checked"));
    });
});
```

And here the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ScnQT/208/